# PeoplePicker Refiner for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

I am working with a custom search refiner display template, and I stumbled into a problem with the People Picker. I don't like that the people picker shows the list of names and you have to click the "Show More" button in order to see the input field. Is there any way to only show the input field, and then show the selected names?

So I want to avoid the list view and only show the input field. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!